# Minimal and maximal subgroup of $C_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

According to Kurzweil/Stellmacher, *Theory of Finite Groups*, page 4:

> A subgroup $U \ne 1$ is a minimal subgroup of $G$ if no other nontrivial subgroup of $G$ is contained in $U$, and a subgroup $U \ne G$ is a maximal subgroup if $U$ is not contained in any other proper subgroup of $G$
>
> Evidently, every nontrivial finite group possesses minimal and maximal subgroups.

So for $C_p$ the only minimal subgroup is $C_p$ itself, and the only maximal subgroup $1$? Just asking if I am right, because that the minimal contains the maximal subgroup properly is odd.

Comment: Yes that is correct. (kinda????)

Comment: Okay, nice to know. "kinda" - do not know, I am not an native english speaker, I removed it, thought I heard that somewhere.